# DownloadManager, never ending notification

Tags: android

****** Now a have completed the code, but the notification display is running again after cancel !

I'm using the DownloadManager for downloading a file by url, it works fine.
Code creating Manager:

```
String[] url = {urlsProz,urlsMb};
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url[i]));
downloadFile=url[i];
request.setDescription("Some description");
request.setTitle("Some titles");
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
}
String s= Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
Log.i("*** testDownloadManager***",s+"/"+url[i]);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(s, "name-of-the-file"+(++j)+".ext");

// get download service and enqueue file
manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
//Download progress will be showing in the notification bar
downloadId=manager.enqueue(request);
Log.i("*** testDownloadManager***","downloadId:"+downloadId);
```

My code after pressing the cancel-Button:

```
if (manager != null) {
    //remove() method will return the number of downloads removed
    //Any downloaded files (complete or partial) will be deleted
    int i = manager.remove(downloadId);
    Log.i(TAG, downloadId + "," + i + " cancelled");
    NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //notifManager.cancelAll(); //doesn'nt work
    manager = null;
}
```

The manager is cancelled but the notification display is still running even after the app.
Any ideas how to cancel this notification ?

Regards Wicki

Comment: Try to cancel it using its ID: `notifManager.cancel(notificationID);`. And make sure you have `notifManager` field inside your class, instead of local variable.

Answer (score 0):

cancelAll() method only cancel notification created by your application.

I think you use DownloadManager as this:

```
// start download
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(urltoDownload));
request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
request.setTitle("my title");
long enqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

So it's DownloadManager app (service) which create notification, and it's only DownloadManager app could cancel it.
You can't cancel other apps notifications, thats not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request dlrequest = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse(url));
    dlrequest
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setTitle("Downloading")
            .setDescription("Downloading in Progress..")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("folder_name", name + ".jpg")
            **.setNotificationVisibility(visibility)**
            .allowScanningByMediaScanner();

    dm.enqueue(dlrequest);
```

.setNotificationVisibility(visibility) -->set visibility true or false. and its done..!